# Shared Preferences showing NullPointerException even when the code is correct

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a simple login and logout session using SharedPreferences. But, I am getting this error :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.chayan.jecrcuniversity, PID: 16940
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor
>   android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.chayan.jecrcuniversity.StudentLogin$1.onClick(StudentLogin.java:40)

Here is my Activity Code:

```
public class StudentLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

Button submit;
EditText un,pass;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Username = "unameKey";
public static final String Password = "passKey";
//public static final String Email = "emailKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String username=un.getText().toString();
            String password=pass.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString(Username, username);
            editor.putString(Password, password);
            editor.apply();

            startActivity(new Intent(StudentLogin.this,MainActivity.class));
                Toast.makeText(StudentLogin.this,"Welcome, "+un.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: `getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` is returning null

Comment: if there is not copy/paste error on your question, I can´t see a reason for this issue. Your sharedPreferences are created after onCreate() which is the correct place for it. Are you using original ROM or custom ROM?

Comment: please deinstall your app and then reinstall....maybe you have made some changes that are not taken over after the new building.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issue with above method try with PreferenceManager class.

To save name in SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, name);
        editor.apply();
```

To get name from SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String name = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "default value");
```

Comment: but this doesn´t help if the questioner don´t want to use the default shared prefs....

Comment: Well..this is not saving my data.

Comment: The code what you have written for storing preferences with our own file and the code i have given for inbuild file name both are working fine. Try to clean your project and run it once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this two methods to save and get value from shared preference.

```
public void savePreferences(Context context,
                                       String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

To get value from `SharedPreferences` use this method:

```
public String getPreferences(Context context, String prefKey) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(prefKey, "");
}
```

**Edit: How to use:**

To save value, use this lines:

```
savePreferences(getApplicationContext(),"KEY","THIS_IS VALUE");
```

To get value, use this lines:

```
getPreferences(getApplicationContext(),"KEY");
```